# How to use pandas in multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multiprocessing

I am developing a script for processing big pandas dataframes. When I try to use `multiprocessing.Pool` with `return` data, it use to much memory.
Is it possible to change dataframes inside a `multiprocessing.Pool` without using `return`.

Here is working code, for example, with `return` data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing


df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]), 
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

def square(col):
    df[col] = df[col] ** 2

    return {'col':col, 'data':df[col]}


with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=16) as pool:
    data = pool.map(square, df.columns) 

for i in data:
    df[i['col']] = i['data']

print(df)
```

I tried to use `multiprocessing.Manager` and `itertools`, but it didn't work or I used them incorrectly.

How can I do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing


df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]), 
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

def square(col):
    df[col] = df[col] ** 2
    # How to save changes here without returning data?


with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=16) as pool:
    data = pool.map(square, df.columns) 


print(df)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much that you can do, the result has to be returned from the process that you have spawned to your main process.

You might want to check out [Modin](https://github.com/modin-project/modin) or [Dask](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/). Also, [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with *loky* backend could help just a bit. Did you run profiling to see what's happening?

Comment: In fact, I was hoping that there was a way to do it simply, but no. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The entire DataFrame needs to be pickled and unpickled for each process. That's why it is very slow and also requires a lot of memory for each process.

You can try to save your data in HDF format (`df.to_hdf`) and reduce memory usage, but in practice it will be too slow.